# How can I display country code and last 3 digits of phone number in Ruby on Rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am a beginner in RoR.
This is the original phone number `+77123456999`

I am going to display it as `+77xxxxxx999`

Here is my `index.html.erb` file code.

```
<tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= user.username %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= user.phone %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= user.email %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= user.state %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

The value of `user.phone` is `+77123456999`
How can I change is as I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use gsub with a regexp:

```
phone_number = "+77123456999"
phone_number.gsub(/(?<=\w{2})\w(?=\w{3})/, 'x')
#=> "+77xxxxxx999"
```